# Authentication for NSFileManager Event

Tags: objective-c, macos, launchd

I want to copy the daemon property list file from my App bundle and paste it in /Library/LaunchDaemons/ with admin privilege. How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [AuthorizationExecuteWithPrivileges example](http://www.michaelvobrien.com/blog/2009/07/authorizationexecutewithprivileges-a-simple-example/) solved my problem.